# SelectedIndexChanged event is not working in asp.net with bootstrap for radio button list

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, autopostback, selectedindexchanged

I am working on asp.net web form web application in asp.net with bootstrap. I am facing a problem. SelectedIndexChanged index change is not worked.

Here is my code:

In aspx file:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblstPaymentMode" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblstPaymentMode_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="CASH" Text="Cash"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="CHEQUE" Text="Cheque"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="PAYORDER" Text="Pay Order"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

In cs file:

```
protected void rblstPaymentMode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(rblstPaymentMode.SelectedValue.Equals("CASH"))
        {
            trPaymentMode.Visible = false;
            rfvChequeBank.Enabled = false;
            rfvChequeDate.Enabled = false;
            rfvChequeNo.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            trPaymentMode.Visible = true;
            rfvChequeBank.Enabled = true;
            rfvChequeDate.Enabled = true;
            rfvChequeNo.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

---

but SelectedIndexChanged is not firing.

I have debug with firebug and i get the following tag for radio radio buttion:

---

```
<div class="iradio_minimal" style="position: relative;" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false">
```

Cash

---

when it become selected then it come:

---

```
<div class="iradio_minimal checked" style="position: relative;" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false">
```

Cash

---

But event is not fire.

I have googled. but no solution found.

Comment: The event is fired. you should looking for problem in elsewhere.
I check the current code and it's working, you can edit question and put complete code if you want.

Comment: Event is fire normally but in bootstrap event is not fire.

Comment: Where is the bootstrap? i can't see any sign of bootstrap in your code. I think your question is completely vague.

Comment: from what ive see in my experience that most of the SelectedIndex_changed event does not fire because you are rebinding something in the Page_load event that has to do with this list, just make sure to debug your page load and see!!